# django-rest-framework + django-polymorphic ModelSerialization

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I was wondering if anyone had a Pythonic solution of combining Django REST framework with django-polymorphic.

Given:

```
class GalleryItem(PolymorphicModel):
    gallery_item_field = models.CharField()

class Photo(GalleryItem):
    custom_photo_field = models.CharField()

class Video(GalleryItem):
    custom_image_field = models.CharField()
```

If I want a list of all GalleryItems in django-rest-framework it would only give me the fields of GalleryItem (the parent model), hence: id, gallery_item_field, and polymorphic_ctype. That's not what I want. I want the custom_photo_field if it's a Photo instance and custom_image_field if it's a Video.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

So far I only tested this for GET request, and this works:

```
class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Photo


class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Video


class GalleryItemModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.GalleryItem

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        """
        Because GalleryItem is Polymorphic
        """
        if isinstance(obj, models.Photo):
            return PhotoSerializer(obj, context=self.context).to_representation(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, models.Video):
           return VideoSerializer(obj, context=self.context).to_representation(obj)
        return super(GalleryItemModuleSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)
```

For POST and PUT requests you might want to do something similiar as overriding the to_representation definition with the to_internal_value def.

Comment: I can't find any documentation for the `to_native` method. When is it called?

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#changes-to-the-custom-field-api

Comment: I'm guessing that POST and PUT may be slightly harder (though still doable) since you need to determine what the user intended to submit, BEFORE validation (if a field is missing, it might be impossible to be certain).

IMHO, it's cleaner to use separate endpoints for write requests.

Comment: Change `to_native` to `to_representation`.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a general and reusable solution. It's for a generic `Serializer` but it wouldn't be difficult to modify it to use `ModelSerializer`. It also doesn't handle serializing the parent class (in my case I use the parent class more as an interface).

```
from typing import Dict, Type

from rest_framework import serializers


class PolymorphicSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """
    Serializer to handle multiple subclasses of another class

    - For serialized dict representations, a 'type' key with the class name as
      the value is expected: ex. {'type': 'Decimal', ... }
    - This type information is used in tandem with get_serializer_map(...) to
      manage serializers for multiple subclasses
    """
    def get_serializer_map(self) -> Dict[str, Type[serializers.Serializer]]:
        """
        Return a dict to map class names to their respective serializer classes

        To be implemented by all PolymorphicSerializer subclasses
        """
        raise NotImplementedError

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        """
        Translate object to internal data representation

        Override to allow polymorphism
        """
        type_str = obj.__class__.__name__

        try:
            serializer = self.get_serializer_map()[type_str]
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError(
                'Serializer for "{}" does not exist'.format(type_str),
            )

        data = serializer(obj, context=self.context).to_representation(obj)
        data['type'] = type_str
        return data

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        """
        Validate data and initialize primitive types

        Override to allow polymorphism
        """
        try:
            type_str = data['type']
        except KeyError:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({
                'type': 'This field is required',
            })

        try:
            serializer = self.get_serializer_map()[type_str]
        except KeyError:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({
                'type': 'Serializer for "{}" does not exist'.format(type_str),
            })

        validated_data = serializer(context=self.context) \
            .to_internal_value(data)
        validated_data['type'] = type_str
        return validated_data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Translate validated data representation to object

        Override to allow polymorphism
        """
        serializer = self.get_serializer_map()[validated_data['type']]
        return serializer(context=self.context).create(validated_data)
```

And to use it:

```
class ParentClassSerializer(PolymorphicSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for ParentClass objects
    """
    def get_serializer_map(self) -> Dict[str, Type[serializers.Serializer]]:
        """
        Return serializer map
        """
        return {
            ChildClass1.__name__: ChildClass1Serializer,
            ChildClass2.__name__: ChildClass2Serializer,
        }
```

Comment: Great solution! Were you able to integrate this with DRF's browse-able documentation?

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with the browse-able docs so I did not.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Quick note: Your serializer map's type should be `Dict[str, Type[serializers.Serializer]]` instead of `Dict[str, serializers.Serializer]`

Answer (score 7):

For sake of completion, I'm adding `to_internal_value()` implementation, since I needed this in my recent project.

**How to determine the type**

Its handy to have possibility to distinguish between different "classes"; So I've added the type property into the base polymorphic model for this purpose:

```
class GalleryItem(PolymorphicModel):
    gallery_item_field = models.CharField()

    @property
    def type(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__
```

This allows to call the `type` as "field" and "read only field".

`type` will contain python class name.

**Adding type to Serializer**

You can add the `type` into "fields" and "read only fields"
(you need to specify type field in all the Serializers though if you want to use them in all Child models)

```
class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Photo

    fields = ( ..., 'type', )
    read_only_fields = ( ..., 'type', )


class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Video

    fields = ( ..., 'type', )
    read_only_fields = ( ..., 'type', )

class GalleryItemModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.GalleryItem

    fields = ( ..., 'type', )
    read_only_fields = ( ..., 'type', )

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        pass # see the other comment

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
    """
    Because GalleryItem is Polymorphic
    """
    if data.get('type') == "Photo":
        self.Meta.model = models.Photo
        return PhotoSerializer(context=self.context).to_internal_value(data)
    elif data.get('type') == "Video":
        self.Meta.model = models.Video
        return VideoSerializer(context=self.context).to_internal_value(data)

    self.Meta.model = models.GalleryItem
    return super(GalleryItemModuleSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
```