# Django rest framework different serializer in the same list

Tags: list, serialization, django-rest-framework, abstract

I have these models:

```
class LogModel(models.Model):
    
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, default=get_current_user, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s")    
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True    
        
        
class FeedPost(LogModel):  
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True   


class ArticleFeedPost(FeedPost):
    article = models.TextField()          


class QuestionFeedPost(FeedPost):
    question = models.TextField()   
    votes = models.IntegerField()
```

And I have these serializers:

```
class ArticleFeedPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = feed_models.ArticleFeedPost


class QuestionFeedPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = feed_models.QuestionFeedPost
```

I would like to set up an endpoint which returns a list of FeedPost (both article and question).
The problem is that an abstract model can't be serialized.
How can I get this list?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution here:
[django-rest-framework + django-polymorphic ModelSerialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976202/django-rest-framework-django-polymorphic-modelserialization)

It require [PolymorphicModel](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Model:

```
class FeedPost(LogModel, PolymorphicModel):  
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)

    class Meta: 
        default_permissions = ('add', 'change', 'delete', 'view')
```

Serializer:

```
class FeedPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = feed_models.FeedPost

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, feed_models.ArticleFeedPost):
            return ArticleFeedPostSerializer(obj, context=self.context).to_representation(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, feed_models.WorkoutFeedPost):
           return QuestionFeedPostSerializer(obj, context=self.context).to_representation(obj)
        return super(FeedPostSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)
```