# How can I generate a rest viewset for all child models based on a parent model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following models based on a shared base model:

```
class Pet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='pet', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name=models.CharField(max=100)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['-created']


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Dog(Pet):

    legs = models.BigIntegerField()


class Bird(Pet):

    wings = models.BigIntegerField()
    cage = models.BigIntegerField()
```

Now I would like to get a rest ViewSet that looks like this when I ask for a User:

```
{
  username: "PeterSchmidt"
  email:"ps@gmail.com"
  pets{
     {
        name="shaggy"
        type="dog"
        legs=4
     }
     {
        name="Jaques"
        type="bird"
        wings=2
        cage=1
     }


}

}
```

Basicly I want a way of having a baseclass model that has its own viewset (multiple serilizers are fine) that I can just use to get all the pets no matter what type they are.
Can this be done within standard django rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `django-polymorphic` to create polymorphic models. General recommendation is that even if the database polymorphism looks clean in the code, it is not recommended thing to do and even if it is not obvious, the code get's more complex.

The way I would solve this would be having one model with diferrent nullable fields for diferrent types, the type choice field and then one wrapper serializer with keys `type, data` where key would be the type of the animal and in data would be serialized animal. This could be done using serialized of the Pet model with one `SerializerMethodField` which will serialize the instance of Pet using diferrent serializer for each type.

[Django polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html)

[Django rest polymorphic](https://github.com/apirobot/django-rest-polymorphic)

[Realated question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19976203/3612571) - There is nicely explained the way ti serialize more models with one serializer

Comment: I think I'll go with the second option then, thanks