# DRF Serializing inherited models

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have two models inheriting same model and i want to serialize them. I couldn't see a way to do it with modelserializer class.

```
class Answer(models.Model):

    submission = models.ForeignKey( Submission, related_name='answers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey( Question, related_name='answers', on_delete=models.CASCADE )

class TextAnswer(Answer):

    answer = models.CharField(max_length=10000 , blank=True)

class IntegerAnswer(Answer):
    answer = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
```

What i want to do is this so i can serialize all the related answers no matter what type they are.

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answers = AnswerSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django-rest-framework + django-polymorphic ModelSerialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19976202/10569220)

Answer (score 0):

One approach I can think of is to use `SerializerMethodFields`:

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answers = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_answers(self, obj)
        return obj.answers.all().values_list('answer', flat=True)
```